# Запрос с join из 4 таблиц

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Есть таблица `complaints`, в ней находятся жалобы пользователя, также есть внешние ключи `user_id`, который связан с таблицей `users`, в которой хранятся пользователи оставившие жалобу, а также `comment_id`, которая связывает ее с таблицей `comments`, где лежит вся информация о комментариях.

В таблице комментариев есть ключ `news_id`, которая указывает к какой новости из таблицы `news` относится новость, а также `user_id`, кто оставил этот комментарий.

**ЗАДАЧА:** выбрать из таблицы жалоб все жалобы, сгруппировать их по комментариям, вытащить информацию о пользователях которые оставили жалобу, а также информацию о комментариях на которые оставлены жалобы, новости к которой относится комментарий и пользователю, который его оставил. Знаю как это сделать за несколько запросов.

Вопросы:

1. Можно ли все это сделать за один запрос?
2. Будет ли этот запрос эффективнее и быстрее чем несколько запросов, то есть большая ли разница по времени исполнения и нагрузке?

Comment: 1 запрос - это 1 `SELECT`?

Comment: точнее нет, это может быть вложенный селект, с множеством селектов внутри

Comment: Если можно, хотелось бы небольшой примерчик. Насчет тестов вы правы, но думал, может можно обойтись и без этого

Answer (score 4, accepted):

например, так (если я правильно расшифровал несколько сумбурное описание желаемого):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ad941/1)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
create table complaints (id int, user_id int, comment_id int, t text);
insert into complaints values
   (1, 1, 1, "жалоба 1")
  ,(2, 1, 2, "жалоба 2")
;

create table users (id int, n text);
insert into users values
   (1, "корябеда")
  ,(2, "сорока")
;

create table comments (id int, news_id int, user_id int, c text);
insert into comments values
   (1, 1, 2, "комментарий 1")
  ,(2, 2, 2, "комментарий 2")
;

create table news (id int, t text);
insert into news values
   (1, "в лесу что-то случилось")
  ,(2, "в лесу всё спокойно")
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select p.n as "ябеда", comments.c as "комментарий"
 , c.n as "комментатор", news.t as "новость"
from complaints
join comments
 on complaints.comment_id = comments.id
join users p
 on complaints.user_id = p.id
join users c
 on comments.user_id = c.id
join news
 on comments.news_id = news.id
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ad941/1/0)**:

```
|    ябеда |   комментарий | комментатор |                 новость |
|----------|---------------|-------------|-------------------------|
| корябеда | комментарий 1 | сорока      | в лесу что-то случилось |
| корябеда | комментарий 2 | сорока      |     в лесу всё спокойно |
```

Comment: Забавный пример ;)

Comment: @ApInvent, «рыба» не обязательно должна быть так же серьёзна, как [труды цицерона](http://ru.lipsum.com/).

Answer (score 2):

У вас есть таблица новостей, *каждая* новость может иметь *несколько* комментариев. *Один* пользователь может оставить *несколько* комментариев и *несколько* жалоб. На *один* комментарий может поступить *несколько* жалоб. Связи можно изобразить так:

```
users \
news  — comments — complaints
           users /
```

Ключевая таблица - news, с нее и начинаем сбор данных.

```
    SELECT n.id newsID,
           c.id commentID,
           uc.id commentatorID,
           ucm.id complainerID
      FROM news n
 LEFT JOIN comments c ON n.id = c.news_id
 LEFT JOIN complaints cm ON c.id = cm.comment_id
 LEFT JOIN users uc ON uc.id = c.user_id
 LEFT JOIN users ucm ON ucm.id = cm.user_id
     WHERE cm.id IS NOT NULL
  ORDER BY n.id,
           c.id;
```

*LEFT JOIN* здесь чтобы ничего не потерять по пути. У комментариев и жалоб по умолчанию есть авторы, но вот могут быть статьи без комментариев и комментарии без жалоб. *WHERE cm.id IS NOT NULL* отсекает новости без комментариев, а также новости с комментариями, на которые не было жалоб.

В роли группировки здесь выступает сортировка.

Эффективность будет зависеть от структуры БД, объемов, используемого движка, наличия индексов.

**UPD** (Немного о том, почему все-таки начинаем сбор данных от таблицы *news*, а не от *complaints*). Задачи доступа к данным имеют тенденцию часто меняться. Поэтому выгоднее построить **один** SQL-запрос, который можно тюнинговать при помощи условий *WHERE...*, чем строить каждый раз новый запрос.

Запрос выше легко модифицировать под несколько задач, только лишь поменяв условие *WHERE...*:

- найти все жалобы на комментарии,
- найти все комментарии без жалоб,
- найти все новости без комментариев вообще,
- найти жалобщиков, которые жалуются на определенных комментаторов.

Второй довод из области [предметно-ориентированного проектирования](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5). В данном примере ключевая сущность - новости. Сами по себе комментарии и жалобы на комментарии не существуют.

Comment: а зачем делать Left Join и в тоже время: **WHERE cm.id IS NOT NULL отсекает новости без комментариев, а также новости с комментариями, на которые не было жалоб.**

Comment: @Bald56rus, расширил свой ответ.